# How to test an ember.js engine route without the ember/no-restricted-resolver-tests eslint error?

Tags: ember.js, eslint

My ember.js app uses an in-repo mountable engine called `user-backoffice`.

This engine provides a route called `my-engine-route`, and here is the unit test for it, located at `my-app/lib/user-backoffice/test-support/unit/my-engine-route/route-test.js`

```js
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { setupTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import engineResolverFor from 'ember-engines/test-support/engine-resolver-for';

const modulePrefix = 'user-backoffice';
const resolver = engineResolverFor(modulePrefix);

module('[user-backoffice] Unit | Route | my-engine-route', function(hooks) {
  setupTest(hooks, {resolver});

  test('it exists', function(assert) {
    let route = this.owner.lookup('route:my-engine-route');
    assert.ok(route);
  });
});
```

The `engineResolverFor` part is taken from the [ember-engine.com docs](https://github.com/ember-engines/ember-engines.com/blob/83c04e2215a3419eb1bb6e09cc75e09ffe04b8fb/markdown/guide/testing.md#unitintegration-testing).

My problem is that this code generates an eslint error because of the [ember/no-restricted-resolver-tests](https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember/blob/master/docs/rules/no-restricted-resolver-tests.md) rule.

```
my-app/lib/user-backoffice/test-support/test-support/unit/my-engine-route/route-test.js
  9:20  error  Do not use setupTest whose last parameter is an object unless used in conjunction with `integration: true`  ember/no-restricted-resolver-tests
```

In my opinion, the eslint rule and the ember-engine docs are in contradiction, so I'd like to know if the rule should be disabled in an engine's context, or if the ember-engine.com docs should be updated.

**EDIT**

@villander suggested in the `emberjs` Discord `#ember-engines` channel that this might be related with the ember version I am using on the project, which is indeed a bit old: 3.8.

Here is a repo to reproduce: https://github.com/bartocc/stackoverflow-question-58007416

Answer (score -1):

@jul Do not send second parameter as in the form of object like wrap it up in { }.

setupTest(hooks, resolver); //this should  fix your problem

Comment: the second parameter passed to `setupTest` must be an object of options, so `setupTest(hooks, {resolver});` is good IMHO.

Comment: Did you test my anwer ? @jul